# Awk: if pattern not found add some text at the end of file

Tags: text-processing, awk

Using `awk`, how we can add text at the bottom, only *if a certain pattern was not found* in the file?

This is not working:

```
awk '{if ($0 !~ /pattern/) {print}; END {print "someText"}}' file
```

The file is small, less than 1MB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should work:

```
awk '/pattern/ {found=1} {print} END{if (!found) print "someText"}' file
```

This will a priori print the entire file (`{print}` rule without conditions) and at that time look for the pattern. If it is found, it sets a flag ( `{found=1}` with the condition `/pattern/`, which is equivalent to `$0 ~ /pattern/`). If that flag is not set at end-of-file, the `"someText"` will be printed.

You can either redirect the output to a new file, as in

```
awk ' <see above> ' file > newfile
```

or, if you have a newer version of GNU `awk`, use the "inplace" editing function (with care!):

```
awk -i inplace ' <see above> ' file
```

Answer (score 8):

another `awk` approch which is about a bit faster on big file size that exits as soon as *pattern* found and append something to the file if *pattern* was not found.

```
awk '/pattern/{found=1; exit}; END{ if(!found) print "append" >>FILENAME }' infile
```

or alternatively using `grep`:

```
<infile grep -q pattern || echo 'appending...' >>infile
```